# Chrome start page: no "Most Visited" nor "Apps", just "Blank" wanted

Tags: google-chrome

```
Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 on OS X 10.8.2
```

How can I get just a plain blank page as my home page, not just a list of "Most Visited" sites or "Apps" installed, please?

I did try using the `about:blank` and/or `javacript:void()` workaround from these sources:

- http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/xTKRGDi6Rb4
- [How to make a blank page in Google Chrome at start-up?](https://superuser.com/questions/206229/how-to-make-a-blank-page-in-google-chrome-at-start-up)

Note the UI has changed since this and I am confused:

- [Chrome "New Tab Page" not showing most frequently visited pages](https://superuser.com/questions/114217/chrome-new-tab-page-not-showing-most-frequently-visited-pages)

I prefer not to install extensions from unknown sources, like recommended here:

- [Make Chrome New Tab Totally Blank](https://superuser.com/questions/383909/make-chrome-new-tab-totally-blank?rq=1)

Comment: Did you look at this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab/pfdloiaebhgmjpaclbbodcmlmppkakjh)?

Comment: Yes, but the question is: _who_ makes this? DarkByte? I don't trust "DARKbyte". How can I make sure it is not bad code or it will not be "software updated" with bad code some day just before I do Internet banking on Chrome? I shun installing software from unknown sources...

Comment: For safe browsing you can use `incognito` mode of Chrome.

Comment: It's not that I want Incognito, I'd just like _not_ to show that I visit some medical sites or things like that often to anybody sitting behind me @ Starbucks? Sounds reasonable?

Comment: Then you can look out on this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) too. Also you can use [speed-dial](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi) plugin and can change your home page or new tab view in settings.

Comment: You can set option `about:blank` in [new tab redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/related) plugin options but it can access your **tabs and browsing activity**. Otherwise there is no way to do this.

Comment: Are you talking about the browser when it starts up or when you open a new tab? The former is easy and I just had to change one little setting. The other I need to continue to research.

Comment: @AlEverett: thx 4 the comment, I mean "open a new tab".

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you'll need an extension for that. There are several out there, though.

Answer (score 1):

The most visited / apps page for new tabs is designed behaviour. You cannot change it to a totally blank page `about:blank` or a specific URL, unless you [use an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna).

The only other alternative is to change the Chromium source code yourself, specifically for `new tab page` http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/ui/webui/ntp/?pathrev=113333

Comment: How is patching a source file maintainable in light of the need to keep the browser up-to-date in terms of security via the update channel and how is a coding answer suitable to SuperUser? ;)

Comment: @Robottinosino my answer does not include any patching of source files. Simply install a Chrome extension. 

Another alternative is to install a few Chrome web apps / extensions and use it a few times. Whenever you open a new tab, Chrome will now default to the Apps page instead of the Most Visited page.