# Chrome not showing the most visited websites

Tags: google-chrome

I have the same problem of: [Chrome "New Tab Page" not showing most frequently visited pages](https://superuser.com/questions/114217/chrome-new-tab-page-not-showing-most-frequently-visited-pages) but my version is 39.0.2171.65 m (64-bit) and my Chrome seems to be storing the Chronology of my visits, but I still can't see my most visited pages.

This is what I see:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you get when you open a new tab?

Comment: edited my question adding a screenshot